Spring authorization server + angular app + oidc-client.ts NoResourceFoundException: No static resource oauth2/authorize 404
I have the below client and security configuration using Spring authorization server
build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}

Client Registration
@Configuration
public class Clients {

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("school-staff")
                .clientSecret("school-staff")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUris( redirectUri-> {
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/");
                    redirectUri.add("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback");
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-renew.html");
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/auth-callback");
                })
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:4200/")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }
}

Security configuration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
                OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();

        http
                .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
                .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, (authorizationServer) ->
                        authorizationServer
                                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults())    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
                )
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/error", "/main.css", "/oauth2/authorize").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin((login) -> login.loginPage("/login"));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

}

Using the OIDC client ts the angular application is using the below configuration
https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts
  openID = {
    authority: 'http://127.0.0.1:5100',
    client_id: 'school-staff',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silentRenewUrl: window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-renew.html',
    renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 10,
    autoUserInfo: false,
  };

200 OK network request
http://127.0.0.1:5100/.well-known/openid-configuration
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK

The network request 404 not found
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5100/oauth2/authorize?client_id=school-staff&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth-callback&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&state=2fdb6a7c30694bd595d0eb24998063dc&code_challenge=HUd0-sH1tKkijeXFoJBMEzURFZL37kK1-Ag8oJR50U8&code_challenge_method=S256", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"131\", \"Chromium\";v=\"131\", \"Not_A Brand\";v=\"24\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
  },
  "referrer": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});

ERROR on browser
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Nov 30 20:29:10 AEDT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource oauth2/authorize.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource oauth2/authorize.


The allow permit was not working so need to add the below configuration code
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();
    http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/jwks").hasAuthority("SCOPE_keys.write"))
            .securityMatchers(matchers ->
                    matchers.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/oauth2/**"), authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher()))
            .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, (authorizationServer) ->
                    authorizationServer.oidc(Customizer.withDefaults()))    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

            // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
            // authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                            new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    ))
        // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
        .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    return http.build();
}

Then everything works
